# Kendo UI Window can't Using

Tags: asp.net

I want use Kendo ui window, but I can't see what the problem is.

```
<div id="window">
</div>
<div id="rightColumn">
    <p>
        <asp:Button Text="Edit Advert" Visible="false" ID="btnEditAdv" CssClass="msgbutton" runat="server" /> 
    </p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var window = $("#window").kendoWindow({
            title: "Centered Window",
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px",
            visible: false
        }).data("kendoWindow");
    });
    $("#btnOpen").click(function () {
        var window = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
        window.center();
        window.open();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *btnOpen* is an HTML button input and is present on the page, this code should work. You may be missing script references to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/).